# Magento 1.x search product by specific value in http queryString

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, javascript, rest-api

Been trying to search how to search item in magento 1.x to return JSON output when requesting something like.

```
www.site.com/api/rest/product?desc=Dress&color=black
```

Been to their doc and the reference they have isn't very clear, as I tried this example and just changed `BlackBerry%208100%20Pearl` to the item I have in my store and it returned `[]`. I'm using a data sample from the download section.

```
http://magentohost/api/rest/products?filter[1][attribute]=name&filter[1][in]=BlackBerry%208100%20Pearl
```

My question is if its possible to have something like my example when searching for products?

Answer (score 0):

Magento documentation isn't very good - it provides an [in] sample with only one parameter.  I assume you want to look for blackberry or pearl?

However, I did some googling - Not sure if this will help but the author said it does work:

```
http://magentohost.com/api/rest/orders?filter[1][attribute]=status&filter[1]
[in][1]=pending&filter[1][in][2]=processing
```

http://magentoforce.com/2014/08/magento-rest-api-multiple-in-get-filters/

If you want to look for blackberry 8200 pearl then you're doing it correctly according to the documentation - do you have a blackberry 8200 pearl in your catalogue?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/get_filters.html

Comment: No I don't have those values, but when I search for the ones I have it returns an empty `[]` array. Looks like it needs a full text search rather than by keyword. What I was trying to do is, if I enter a word e.g Pearl it would return all the items with the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

@mrnew perhaps try using a different parameter to confirm whether the API is returning any data at all. I am not 100% familiar with M1 REST. I have used the SOAP APIs and can confirm that they're reliable.

In regards to your question - it doesn't appear that there is a 'like' operator for Magento 1 REST.  But you could try to see if Like '%what you want to search%' works? Perhaps someone else has more experience.

However, there is a like filter for the Magento 1 SOAP API - my advice is to use SOAP because it is the more established of the APIs, has more features and better documentation.  There are two versions of the SOAP API for Magento 1 - V1, the original API which can also be used via XML-RPC - which defined methods such as call, multicall, login, etc.  V2 defined all services and objects in a WSDL so you can easily generate calls, depending on what you're using to retrieve data.

https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/web-services-api-filter-operators

Comment: I managed to make it work now, but when filtering for an item like 'Sunglasses' it seems to expect a full name like 'Aviator Sunglasses'. Was wondering if there's a way to do a search parameter by just keywords. like `filter...name=Sunglasses` and returns every sunglasses items.